# iOS message like functionality - swipe to reveal message times?

Tags: ios, message, uipangesturerecognizer

I really like the message functionality where i swipe and can see message times. I was browsing stack overflow for this but could not fine something that is working.

If there is some 3rd library I am eager to use it, other than that, i would like to implement this...

I was figuring of adding pan recognizer to table and then on pan shifting all the cells to left revealing message times.

If someone has already implemented this some pointer would be welcome

Comment: this is also implemented in whisper app, there must be a simple way to do this

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. So it would be better to update your question according [SO rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good one from one of my colleagues..

https://github.com/shaps80/iMessageStyleReveal